# How to create a app that simulates bluetooth in windows phone 8.0?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I want to make a app that simulates bluetooth in windows phone 8, I have a page with a serch button and a list where my bluetooth should show the devices with bluetooth in range when I hit serch. I don't know how to make the bluetooth to serch for devices what api should I use?
I'm working on windows phone 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

How about the WP8 Bluetooth API?...[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
    async void AppToApp()
    {

        // PeerFinder.Start() is used to advertise our presence so that peers can find us. 
        // It must always be called before FindAllPeersAsync.
        PeerFinder.Start();

        var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I did that but shows me only the device's which once connected the phone.I need to see all the devices in range with the bluetooth activated

Comment: @user3497559 Have you tried out this sample? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Bluetooth-app-to-device-644870ba

Comment: If you go to the MSDN page for FindAllPeerAsync method at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.findallpeersasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1. It states 'When the asynchronous browsing operation finishes successfully, it returns a list of peers that are within wireless range. A peer is a device that has an app running in the foreground with a matching app Id.' Isn't that what you want?